# Minimax estimators in Bayesian analysis

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, estimators, minimax

I got recently introduced to minimax methods in statistical decision theory. Is there an analogue in Bayesian analysis and some resources related to this?

Comment: I suggest you read a textbook on Bayesian Analysis and Decision Theory, best of all, Jim Berger's 1985 book. He details the connection between Bayes estimators and minimaxity, related to the link between minimax and maximin. Actually, in many instances, it is easier to find a minimax estimator by proceeding through Bayesian arguments.